# ios change size of view dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I change the size of a view programmatically in iOS.

I am developing an iOS app in Objective C.

I have a couple of views which are hidden and shown according to a certain logic using the following method:

```
-(void)hideGroupStats{
    [groupTimeToFinishForeText setHidden:YES];
    [lblTimeToFinish setHidden:YES];
    [groupTimeToFinishBG setHidden:YES];
}
```

below them in my view hierarchy there is a view holding a map with "scale to fit mode".
however, when the other views are hidden it doesnt resize to take the space.

i am new to ios development so i could be missing somting very simple.

Comment: you are just hide Your view , so they are disappear not removed From superview!! got it?? So instead Hiding you have to remove that view from superview and add them back as your condition became true or false!

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I am using storyboards.

Comment: i have tried [groupTimeToFinishBG removeFromSuperview];

Comment: @user2552795, then instead of setting the frame manually it should be more convenient to use  [Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Apple documentation for `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html) (see extract below) when calling `setHidden:YES` this doesn't actually remove the view from it's superview it just makes it disappear so it is equivalently still there you just can't see it. There are a couple of ways to hide the view so you get the affect that you are after but the main one I'd go with is altering the `UIView`s frame (like `David Ansermot`s as says given +1)

```
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
```

with `newX`, `newY`, `newWidth` and `newHeight` all being variables that you set somewhere to determine the size and location of the `UIView`. However I'd stick this line within some sort of animation to give the user a better user experience so I'd personally do something like :

```
- (void)showView:(UIView *)view withAnimationForFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    view.frame = CGRectMake(frame); 

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)hideView:(UIView *)view withAnimationForFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    view.frame = CGRectMake(frame); 

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Changing the frame size and/or location should make the other views that you want to scale do it automatically like you want.

**[Extract from Apple Documentation for UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html)**

> Setting the value of this property to `YES` hides the receiver and setting it to `NO` shows the receiver. The default value is `NO`.
>
> A hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and participates in autoresizing as usual. Hiding a view with subviews has the effect of hiding those subviews and any view descendants they might have. This effect is implicit and does not alter the hidden state of the receiver’s descendants.
>
> Hiding the view that is the window’s current first responder causes the view’s next valid key view to become the new first responder.
>
> The value of this property reflects the state of the receiver only and does not account for the state of the receiver’s ancestors in the view hierarchy. Thus this property can be `NO` but the receiver may still be hidden if an ancestor is hidden.

Comment: is there a way to get the height of the removed view and of the map view so it could scale up to the right size?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add code to resize your view like :

```
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly set the frame of your view like:-

[yourViewObject  SetFrame :CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight)];

And if you want to set the frame of your view on dependent any other view(map view) then you can simply use :-

```
yourviewObj.frame  = mapview.frame
```

Hope this will be helpful for you